# OpenGL Shader Version Compile Error

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I have a problem when compiling a simple vertex shader in OpenGL, I get the following error messages:

- error(#106) Version number not supported by GL2
- error(#279) Invalid layout qualifier 'location'

I assume that I must be using the wrong version of GL2, but I have no idea how to find my version number or where to go for an upgrade (and yes I tried to search for an answer.) Attached is a copy of my shader code just for reference and my openGL information.

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;

void main() {
    gl_Position.xyz = Position;
}
```

- Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
- Renderer: ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series
- Version: 3.2.9756 Compatibility Profile Context

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but doesn't `#version 330` mean you're requiring GLSL 3.3, and therefore OpenGL 3.3?  Check to make sure that you're requesting an OpenGL context of a sufficiently-high version; there were a lot of changes between 2.x and 3.x which were NOT backwards-compatible.

Comment: honestly, I'm not sure. I checked online and the GLSL versions don't seem to match up with the version tag. I know I can get around this by not requiring a verison and using glGetAttribLocation in the code, but I'd like to get this working in it's current state if possible.

Comment: Try using a lower version (such as #version 150) of shaders and see if they compile.

Comment: It does, actually I just pulled out the version number, although now I am having trouble getting glew and intillisense to work on my home computer, so I can't do further testing until tomorrow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#version 330 core
```

This says that your shader uses GLSL version 3.30.

This:

> Version: 3.2.9756 Compatibility Profile Context

Means that your OpenGL version is 3.2. [The GLSL version that corresponds with OpenGL 3.2 is 1.50.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Core_Language#Version) Which is less than 3.30. Hence the lack of compilation.

Update your drivers; those are extremely old. Your card should be able to support GL 4.2.