# Can't compile simple vertex shader

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, vertex-shader

I've got a problem with compiling a simple vertex shader. I'm using this function for compiling:

```
GLuint TShaderManager::loadShaderFromFile(const std::string& fName, GLenum shaderType)
{
    string path = fName;

    //Open file 
    GLuint shaderID = 0; 
    string shaderString; 
    ifstream sourceFile(path.c_str()); 

    //Source file loaded 
    if(sourceFile) 
    { 
        shaderString.assign(istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile), 
                            istreambuf_iterator<char>());                                           // Get shader source

        shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);                                                      // Create shader ID 

        const GLchar* shaderSource = shaderString.c_str(); 
        glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, (const GLchar**)&shaderSource, NULL);                           // Set shader source 

        glCompileShader(shaderID);                                                              // Compile shader source 

        GLint shaderCompiled = GL_FALSE; 
        glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shaderCompiled);                                //Check shader for errors 
        if(shaderCompiled != GL_TRUE) 
        { 
            TError::showMessage("Failed to compile shader"); // I'm getting this error 
            glDeleteShader(shaderID); 
            shaderID = 0; 
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        TError::showMessage(string("Unable to open file ").append(path.c_str())); 
    } 

    return shaderID;
}
```

This is my vertex shader that doesn't compile:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

So basically `shaderCompiled` remains `GL_FALSE`.

I checked in debug mode - shader is properly loaded as a `string` in my function, so problem is not there.

Also I don't know if that's necessary, but I'm putting here also my fragment shader which compiles properly:

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
    float lerpValue = gl_FragCoord.y / 800.0f;

    outputColor = mix(vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                      vec4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f), lerpValue);
}
```

**Edit:**

`glGetShaderInfoLog` shows this message:

> ERROR: 0:3 'location': syntax error parse error

Comment: Try [glGetShaderInfoLog](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) for additional information; perhaps it hints at the error.

Comment: @StefanHanke It shows this message: ERROR: 0:3 'location': syntax error parse error

Comment: Stop **YELLING AND BOLDFACING** your text. We can find the important parts of your post without **RANDOM EMPHASIS**.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not yelling and I'm not overusing boldfacing. It's there for some reason, though. I just wanted to make my text more clear and I think it's better this way. Of course I don't like when someone is using it for some random emphasis as you did in your comment.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631437/opengl-shader-version-compile-error

Comment: TYPING IN ALL CAPS is considered "yelling" on [so] and internet in general.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I know that. I wasn't writing all sentences with caps. Do you really consider my 4 words as yelling? That's just ridiculous, I must admit. :-) But I'm not going to argue about it here.

Comment: @Vlad Thank you very much! I didn't find that question before.